# GridPane: How to position a Label top-left?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

How can I position the `Label` *Label 1* at the top-left position of the cell? I tried to set the alignment of the label accordingly, but this didn't do the trick.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane hgap="14.0" vgap="7.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="400.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints />
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="Label 1" />
      <VBox spacing="4.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
         <children>
            <HBox spacing="4.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField styleClass="" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <tooltip>
                        <Tooltip style="-fx-font-size: 100%;" text="Subject 1; Subject 2; Subject 3" />
                     </tooltip>
                  </TextField>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" maxHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="61.0" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <Label text="Label 2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="4.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <children>
            <TextField HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Hyperlink text="duplicate" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the first [RowConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html) and set the [valignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html#valignmentProperty) property to `VPos.TOP`.

> The vertical alignment for the row. If set, will be the default
> vertical alignment for nodes contained within the row. If this
> property is set to VPos.BASELINE, then the fillHeight property will be
> ignored and nodes will always be resized to their preferred heights ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html#valignmentProperty)).

Like this:

```xml
[...]
<rowConstraints>
   <RowConstraints valignment="TOP" vgrow="SOMETIMES" /> <!-- added valignment="TOP" -->
   <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   <RowConstraints />
   <RowConstraints />
</rowConstraints>
[...]
```